# How and where to use formkey?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

after migration of some tables of customers from magento 1.7.0.2 to magento 2.1.8 . I am unable to create a new customer account. Like customer is unable to signup . SomeOne told me I have to paste  form key   `<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`
  in `Module_customer / register.phtml`
. So where I can paste this ?  Is it really a case ?

Comment: its can be a case but i believe magento 2 uses form key in all forms by default, so its unlikely that its the case.

Comment: @SunilVerma I dont have in register.phtml :(  . where to place and check ?

Comment: add <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?> after form tag before fieldset tag starts and check.

Comment: Mean where form end </form> after that ? @SunilVerma   and  =  instead of echo ?

Comment: nope where it starts i.e after <form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

Comment: @SunilVerma   I did like this    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>   <form class="form create account form-create-account" ......

Comment: please add it after <form tag finishes it should be inside <form> and </form> tag

Comment: @SunilVerma  can you look into it please ?  https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/458